# unexpected token `<' when calling from parent file

Tags: shell-script

I am writing a config generator script.

When I paste the function code (`setup_displays`) directly in the terminal everything works. But when I call `sh generator.sh` I get this error:

```
functions.sh: line 3: ./helpers.sh: Permission denied
functions.sh: line 75: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
functions.sh: line 75: `  done< <(echo $display_result)'
```

generator.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
source functions.sh
setup_display
```

functions.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
source ./helpers.sh

setup_display() {
 display_result=2 87 800 600 60 1 0 0 0

  # setting params
  while read -r hdmi_group hdmi_mode hdmi_cvt; do
    echo "hdmi_mode" "$hdmi_mode"
    echo "hdmi_group" "$hdmi_group"
    echo "hdmi_cvt" "$hdmi_cvt"
  done< <(echo $display_result)    # line 75
}
```

This is the correct output

```
hdmi_mode 87
hdmi_group 2
hdmi_cvt 800 600 60 1 0 0 0
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: Don't run it with `/bin/sh` - it doesn't provide "process substitution". e.g. `bash` does. And, use double quotes when assigning `display_result`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#!/bin/sh` is not equivalent to `#!/bin/bash`.

Anyway: this is useless use of echo. Use

```
done <<<$display_result
```

instead.

Comment: wow, thank you very much! It worked immediately!